# Xamarin alert failing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Getting error when i call the `UIAlertView`:

```
/Users/sun/Projects/csharp/csharp/ViewController.cs(13,13): Warning CS0618: 'UIAlertView.UIAlertView(string, string, UIAlertViewDelegate, string, params string[])' is obsolete: 'Use overload with a IUIAlertViewDelegate parameter' (CS0618) (csharp)
```

[image]

Code:

```
    void HandleTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Touch2", "TouchUpInside handled", null, "OK", null).Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning and error are two different things.

Error:

The invalid selector on the `TouchUpInside` can be caused be a few different things, since you did not post code on how you are setting it up, but I would look at if you have any additional actions for the button assigned in the Storyboard, if the button (or its ViewController) is going out of scope, etc..

Warning:

> Warning CS0618: 'UIAlertView.UIAlertView(string, string, UIAlertViewDelegate, string, params string[])' is obsolete:

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8, so if you are targeting iOS 9+, you should use UIAlertController

```
var uiAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Touch2", "TouchUpInside handled", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
uiAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (alertAction) => { 
    alertAction.Dispose(); 
    uiAlert.Dispose(); 
}));
await PresentViewControllerAsync(uiAlert, true);
```

Comment: https://github.com/shamun/ios-samples/tree/master/ButtonEventDemo - Failing when i add the Alert code of yours to ButtonEventDemoViewController.cs. Any idea? why the UIAlertController not working either?

Comment: @YumYumYum That Xamarin sample runs fine for me. Which `Xamarin.iOS` version and Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode 9.2 , Xamarin.iOS Version: 11.6.1.2 (Visual Studio Community).  It works when i used as : without await  ` 
      aButton.TouchUpInside += (o, s) => {
        Console.WriteLine("button touched using a TouchUpInside event");
        var uiAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Touch2", "TouchUpInside handled", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        uiAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (alertAction) => {
          alertAction.Dispose();
          uiAlert.Dispose();
        }));
        PresentViewControllerAsync(uiAlert, true);
      };`